# How to force regional letters to appear correctly in OOP structure with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, character-encoding

How would I go about forcing national letters such as the Danish Æ, Ø and Å letters, in an OOP structure, where the individual .php documents that are concerned with the query and the output, are not under the charset of the HTML doc?

To be more specific I have an index.php file with the following div:

```
<div id="box_tekst"></div>
```

I then have the page.js document concerned with handling the asynchronized requests

```
page.content = function(id) {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'core/page.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { method: 'content', id: id },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#box_tekst').html(data);
        }

    });

}
```

Finally I have the page.php file refered to in the .js document which serves the query in the following maner:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$page = new Page();
$content = $page->getPage($id);

if(!empty($content)) {

    foreach($content as $input) { 
    ?>
        <h1><?= ucfirst($input['title']) ?></h1>
        <p><?= nl2br(ucfirst($input['pg'])) ?></p>
    <?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php allows to modify the http response header using the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

For exemple the above line sets the response charset to utf-8.

Comment: Excellent. And where would I insert this header? I tried all my .php files, to no avail.

Comment: it should lie at the very beginning of the php file that generates the response(core/page.php) at least before any echo or print.

Comment: That's what I tried as well. I added it to the page.php file first, with no result. Then I tried adding it as the first line to the init.php file required onto page.php and index.php. This still didn't help. I also tried just including the plain text before any other file inclusion were done. I'm a bit blank as to where to go from here.

But you have been helpful, no doubt. The utf-8 format is perfect for my case as well.

Comment: For some reason it works when I swap it over to ISO-8859-1 instead. I don't know why UTF-8 doesn't work.. But it works now, so thank you!